# missing delimeter (.inserted) error

Tags: equations, errors

I am entering this formula with this code:

```
\begin{equation}
 P (Y\bigg\mid X) =  \frac{P(X\bigg\mid Y)*P(Y)}{P(X)}
\end{equation}
```

and i am getting the error above.
Thanks for your help.
Tal
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // BTW, use \times for multiplications.

Comment: Note that the `\Set` example in the `mathtools` manual page 27 can be adapted to give a macro, say `\PP` with the syntax `\PP{Y \given X}` where `\PP[\Big]{Y \given X}` will scale the `()`'s and the `|`.

Answer (score 2):

`\mid` is a relation not a delimiter and can not be used with `\bigg` use `\mid` or `\bigg|` (or `\mathrel{\bigg|}`)

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \mid 
l.6  P (Y\bigg\mid
                   X) =  \frac{P(X\bigg\mid Y)*P(Y)}{P(X)}
?
```

`\bigg`  is much too big though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 P (Y\bigg| X) =  \frac{P(X\bigg| Y)\cdot P(Y)}{P(X)}
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation}
 P (Y\mid X) =  \frac{P(X\mid Y)\cdot P(Y)}{P(X)}
\end{equation} 


\begin{equation}
 P (Y\mathrel{\bigg|} X) =  \frac{P(X\mathrel{\bigg|} Y)\cdot P(Y)}{P(X)}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```